# const char* 's in C++

Tags: c++, string

How does string expressions in C++ work?

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    const char *tmp="hey";
    delete [] tmp;

    return 0;
}
```

Where and how is the "hey" expression stored and why is there segmentation fault when I attempt to delete it?

Comment: This code is a bug. You cannot delete a literal.

Comment: I think the questioner understands that much, Pavel. The question asks *why*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Where it's stored is left to the compiler to decide in this (somewhat special) case.  However, it doesn't really matter to you - if you don't allocate memory with `new`, it's not very nice to attempt to deallocate it with `delete`.  You cannot `delete` memory allocated in the way you have allocated it.

If you want to control the deallocation of that resource, you should use a `std::string`, or allocate a buffer using `malloc()`.

Comment: oh... so it's not very recommended to use pointers on const char data i suppose

Comment: @Pyjong: You are free to use a pointer to reference const char data, just don't try to delete the memory referenced by the pointer.

Comment: @Nick, I would add too that if you allocate with `malloc`, you should also be sure to free with `free`.

Comment: @Nick Meyer: Good point.  That seemed beyond the scope of the current discussion somehow.. :-)

Answer (score 18):

When you assign a `const char *` pointer to a constant string like `"hey"` in the example, the `hey\0` sequence is stored as a static variable inside the binary itself.  It cannot be deleted, and should not be manipulated.  Depending on the architecture/operating system, it *may segfault when manipulated*.

If you were to do `const char[] tmp = "hey"` then the data would be stored on the stack, and may be manipulated (but not deleted, as it will be freed once the stack clears: when the function returns).

Do not `delete[]` anything that isn't `new[]`'d.

Answer (score 10):

The `"hey"` is a string literal and is stored in the executable's *data segment*, which is mapped into memory of the process at load time. The particular part where literals live is mapped *read-only*. Here's a snippet of the assembly produced from your code with `g++ -S`:

```
...
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "hey"
    .text
    .align 2
...
```

So the data is indeed *read-only*, and attempt to manipulate it with `delete` leads to segfault.

Answer (score 5):

`const char *tmp="hey";`

"hey" is stored in a [read-only area of the Data Segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).
When the application starts up "hey" will be mapped to the READ-ONLY memory page.

```
const char *tmp="hey";
delete [] tmp;
```

`delete` will [access and change some allocation metadata.](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/128542-how-c-telsl-number-element-delete),
but "hey" in the READ-ONLY memory page.

Changing value in READ-ONLY is not allowed, [so segmentation fault happened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366786%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete static resources: those are Read-Only.

Answer (score 4):

What happens is this.

`"hey"` means *put string 'hey' into binary image somewhere and give me an address of it*, which is the value of the expression ("hey"). It has type char*. At this address, you have 4 bytes. 'h', 'e', 'y', and 0 (0 is called conventional null-terminator. (nothing to do with the movie terminator) This is how string literals work in C.

You can pass this literal as such: "an address of a string".

You cannot delete it.

when you construct std::string("hey"), it takes this pointed string, and copies it elsewhere - into a newly allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete constant data. You would only call `delete[] tmp` if you had previously called `new char[stringSize]`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not call `new` on the string. That is a potential memory leak anyway, for every `new` there is a `delete`, likewise same for `malloc` and `free`. You deleted a memory reference to a pointer that simple is a static array of chars, in the sense of the word.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

The string `"hey"` has its space pre-allocated as part of the program, so it just appears when the program starts and disappears when the program ends.

If you want to see a program that allocates memory, uses it, then deletes it, then look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    const char *hey="hey";
    char* tmp=new char[4]; // NB allocate 4 chars for "hey" plus a null terminator
    strcpy(tmp,hey);  // copies the string and null terminator
    cout << tmp << endl;
    delete [] tmp;
    // must not use tmp now as it points to deallocated memory
    // must not delete hey

    return 0;
}
```

Notice how I happened to delete the `new`'d memory using `tmp`.  I could have done this:

```
    cout << tmp << endl;
    hey = tmp;
    delete [] hey;
```

It doesn't matter whether, in the end, we point to the `new`'d memory with `hey` or `tmp`, just as long as we delete it properly to avoid memory leaks.