# C++ | temporary pointers lifetime

Tags: c++, arrays, rvalue

I'm studying C++ and in all my "experiments" i'm trying to understand temporary objects (rvalues) lifetime.

My question is:

> Having an object which contains a const char* pointer, what happens when i want to use a constructor which takes "const char*" as argument? Usually temporary objects get destructed automatically but what happens with pointers created in this way?

I'm not using std::string or other c++11 classes for now because I'm just focusing on understanding rvalueness.

An example below:

```
class MyAwesomeClass {

private:
    const char* data;

public:
    MyAwesomeClass(const char* ptr) {

        this->data = ptr;
    }

    MyAwesomeClass(MyAwesomeClass&& myAwesomeClassRVALUE) {

        this->data = myAwesomeClassRVALUE.data;
        myAwesomeClassRVALUE.data = nullptr;
    }

    ~MyAwesomeClass() {

        delete data;
    }
};

int main() {

    MyAwesomeClass s = "My Awesome Class' string data.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have two unrelated question. Please pick one and create a [MRE] for it.

Comment: You still need to create a [MRE]. You ask about something that happens in the constructor. Keep the constructor and maybe 1 more method to show how you intend to use the class. The rest of the code must go.

Comment: `std::string* stringData;` I'd reject a CL with that in a struct/class without very persaussive justification, none of which I can invent would apply here.

Comment: The `String` class seems irrelevant to your question. It seems that you're really asking "Does a `std::string` created from a C-style string depend on the original C-style string"? Also, the fact that you use a `std::string*` suggests that you don't understand what `std::string` is.

Comment: unrelated to your question:  `: public Object` it looks like you are trying to emulate `Java` where all class inherit from one `Object`. What's up with that?

Comment: I'm modifying my question in order for you to understand my doubts.
@bolov yes I'm trying to emulate java (just for educational purposes). That structure has been done in order for me to have a virtual "toString" method.

Comment: Why do you think you can implement a copy constructor as `noexcept`, if the `std::string` constructor you're using in it makes no such guarantees? Also why make `stringData` a pointer? This just complicates the memory management. (If you want copies to refer to the same data, use `std::shared_ptr<std::string>()`.)

Comment: I changed my question, i hope it is better now

Comment: I disagree that `String` is not relevant to the question. Strings are often treated differently in the standard library. Anyway I want to congratulate you, not a lot of new users do the required edits to the question.

Comment: Are you asking about the string literal prvalue (the first constructor) or the move constructor? What temporaries do you think exist, and what do you expect to happen to them?

Comment: Hello @Useless, I'm assuming that for the second constructor, the rvalue object gets deleted after the constructor execution and the inner data gets passed from the rvalue to the newly created MyAwesomeClass object. I just don't know what is the lifetime of the const char* pointer, should I consider it as a simple pointer (like the ones created by using new operator) or does it receive some kind of deletion after the execution of my first constructor? In this case my internal pointer would point to invalid memory data.

Comment: The pointer is a value type, like an integer. It's a dumb pointer (unlike say `std::unique_ptr`), so nothing special happens to the thing it points to, which is the string literal. This is the same for all raw (that is, dumb, not smart) pointers, and there is no interaction at all with move semantics or constructors.

Answer (score 1):

> Usually temporary objects get destructed automatically but what happens with pointers created in this way?

Pointers are objects themselves. Same thing happens to temporary pointer objects as happens to all other temporary objects.

Your example deletes a pointer pointing to a string literal, so the behaviour of the program is undefined. The class would also have a broken assignement operators even if it was used correctly by passing pointer to an array allocated with `new[]`.

As for rvalueness, the only rvalue expression in the example that I could find is `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

*Note* this answer is based on a previous edit of the question where `MyAwesomeClass` was a `String` class.

Your `String` class is not really a string class as it doesn't own the underlying string data. It's more akin to [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

You have two avenues I can see you can pursue:

1. Your class owns the underlying data. In this case the class is a wrapper around `std::string` and has std::string`data member. Look up composition. No need to worry about lifetime as`std::string` is well behaved.
2. Your class is like a "pointer/reference/view" to another string. In this case you have a `const char*` and maybe `std::size_t` size data member. You basically have a `std::string_view` (except for the wisdom, expertise and experience that went into designing `std::string_view`). Since you don't own the underlying data you can't do anything about the lifetime of the underlying data. The user of the class must make sure it doesn't end with a "YourStringView" to an expired object, just as he/she needs to make sure it doesn't end up with a reference/pointer to an expired object.

The semantics of these two scenarios are wildly different (as the difference between an object and a pointer to an object).

---

Anyway I wouldn't recommend you do any of this except for maybe learning reasons. `std::string_view` already exists so just use that. If you want the printing capabilities use the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) or the C++ format library (that is based on the mentioned fmt library).

Even if you decide to do this for learning purposes I highly encourage you look into these alternatives and learn from how they are doing things.

---

> ```
> MyAwesomeClass(const char* ptr)
> {
>     this->data = ptr;
> }
>
> ~MyAwesomeClass()
> {
>     delete data;
> }
> ```

Oh no, no, no! No!!

Please look into [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and rule of [0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Your class either owns the pointed object or it doesn't. If it owns it then it is responsible for creating it and deleting it. If it doesn't then it can't do either. You can't have "half of responsibilities" where you are responsible for deleting it but not for creating it.

In user code you should **never** need to manually manage memory. Use the rule of 0.

Comment: "*You can't have "half of responsibilities" where you are responsible for deleting it but not for creating it.*" You very much can do that, and it's fine in many cases. What's *not* fine is the particular case of 1) implicit conversion from a pointer of unknown origin and ownership to owning that pointer (that is, when you adopt an object, there should be *no question* that this is what you meant to do), and 2) the specific usage of `char const*`, which is very likely to be a literal string and thus not owned by you.

Comment: Thank you @bolov for your references, i'm reding it. Furthermore, according to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001286/const-char-s-in-c#:~:text=When%20you%20assign%20a%20const,it%20may%20segfault%20when%20manipulated one should not delete const char pointers since they are allocated in READ-ONLY area (so it's not the case of the "new" operator or malloc). This means that my destructor has a problem (even if no crashes occurred so far) and it's not using the "delete[]" statement but only "delete". Would you accept this code if this->data was created with new/malloc operators?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is that your class does not own the data, but just the raw pointer. Under certain conditions you will see a problem with delete operator. Raw pointer are not great tool to ensure correct object ownership.